# What is type error while finding the accuracy_score?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-science

```
accuracy=accuracy_score(y_test,prediction)
print("accuracy: %.2f%%" % (accuracy*100.0))
```

I tried with this code but it gives me type error

Comment: what's the data type of  accuracy ?

Comment: please include the entire error string! what is the `type()` of accuracy? you may find f-strings or the `.format()` method is friendlier too

Comment: F-string example:  `print(f"accuracy: {accuracy : .2f}%")`

Comment: @Chris, `f"accuracy: {accuracy:.2%}"`

Comment: @OlvinRoght Good, but provides different behavior from the line of code the OP has shown.

Comment: If [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html) is the `accuracy_score` function being used, it should return `float`.

Comment: @Chris, no, it provides exactly the same behavior while your option missing multiply to 100.

Comment: You're correct. I missed the multiplication by 100.

Comment: @PavanShinde, if you comment out the `print` do you still have the type error?

Comment: @Chris yes it still shows error